# Numpy: Efficient Way To Extract Subarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large two dimentional numpy array `A` of dimension around `250000 x 30` and two one dimensional numpy arrays `x` and `y`. I want to extract the sub-array of A with rows in `x` and columns in `y`. Which method is more efficient?

1. `A[x[:,np.newaxis], y]`
2. `A[np.ix_(x,y)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Benchmark it!

```
import numpy as np

# some data
A = np.random.random((250000, 30))

# some random indices
x = np.random.randint(0, 250000, 150000)
y = np.random.randint(0, 30, 10)

def method1(A, x, y):
    return A[x[:, np.newaxis], y]

def method2(A, x, y):
    return A[np.ix_(x,y)]

def method3(A, x, y):
    return A[x][:,y]

def method4(A, x, y):
    return A[:,y][x]
```

These three methods give the following benchmarks:

```
method1: 87.7 ms
method2: 89.2 ms
method3: 115 ms
method4: 141 ms
```

So, the answer is that there is not real difference between the two methods in the question.